# Microsoft Visual Studio not printing last lines

Tags: c, visual-studio, printf, scanf

I have homeword due soon and I tried many ways to compile my C files, but it would never work and finally I could get it working with Microsoft Visual Studio. But, for some reason, it isn't compiling the last two `printf` commands.
When running the compiled .exe file, the first, second and third `scanf` work, but it automatically terminates after the 3rd `scanf`. My friend from uni said it could be a bug.
PS: The language is estonian and if you'd like me to translate, ask.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int vanus;
int pikkus;
int lemmik;
int main()
{
    /* Küsin kasutaja vanust ning vastan. */
    printf("Kui vana sa oled? ");
    scanf("%d",&vanus);
    printf("Sa oled %d aastat vana.\n",vanus);
    /* Küsin kasutaja pikkust ning vastan. */
    printf("Kui pikk sa oled (cm)? ");
    scanf("%d",&pikkus);
    printf("Sa oled %d cm pikk.\n",pikkus);
    /* Küsin kasutaja lemmiknumbrit ning vastan. */
    printf("Mis on sinu lemmiknumber? ");
    scanf("%d",&lemmik);
    printf("Sinu lemmiknumber on %d",lemmik);
    printf("Sa oled %d aastane %d cm pikk ning sinu lemmiknumber on %d",vanus,pikkus,lemmik);
}
```

Comment: use `fflush(stdout);` that'll work

Comment: Add a `printf("\n");` statement as the last line of your program. The end of line char will typically flush stdout.

Comment: Also, don't forget to add a `return 0` as the very last line of `main` before the `}` char.

Comment: VS does not print anything - it is your program :)

Comment: So, what is it? If it does not compile, there is no `exe`. If there is one, it is not recent.